# Array of structures vs structure of arrays in JSON

Tags: json

Let I have an array of structures in JSON like this:

```
[{
    "name": "Amrit",
    "second_name": "Valentine"
},
{
    "name": "Beatriz",
    "second_name": "Carty"
}// And so on...
]
```

It is human readable, but the issue with it is that `"name"` and `"second_name"` are repeated for all entities in this array. And if the array is big, it creates about 40% size overhead.

On the other hand, I could translate this data structure:

```
{
    "names": ["Amrit", "Beatriz" /* ... */],
    "second_names": ["Valentine", "Carty" /* ... */]
}
```

But it is not human readable any longer, but the size is optimal. It is also error prone, since it is not guaranteed that sizes of `"names"` and `"second_names"` are the same.

Is there any trade-off in JSON, so I can use array of structures without repeating filed names and the size is still optimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as part of JSON itself, no. What I've done on projects is a generic system where the JSON would look like this:

```
{
    "__keys__": ["name", "second_name"],
    "values": [
        ["Amrit", "Valentine"],
        ["Beatriz", "Carty"]
    ]
}
```

...where once I've parsed the JSON, I throw a utility function at it to consume that and turn it into an array of objects. Along these lines:

```js
const json = `{
        "__keys__": ["name", "second_name"],
        "values": [
            ["Amrit", "Valentine"],
            ["Beatriz", "Carty"]
        ]
    }`;
const parsed = JSON.parse(json);
const expanded = expand(parsed);

console.log(expanded);

function expand(data) {
    const keys = data.__keys__;
    return data.values.map(entry => {
        const obj = {};
        keys.forEach((key, index) => {
            obj[key] = entry[index];
        });
        return obj;
    });
}
```

Or, of course, you just leave off `__keys__` and assume your endpoint knows what the keys should be, but it impairs readability/debugging even more than the above does. :-)

---

*(You can shoehorn that `forEach` into a `reduce`, because you can shoehorn just about any array operation into a `reduce`, but it doesn't buy you anything.)*